# Get item in sub array and put back to main array

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I have a problem when get item in sub array and put back to main array by javascript.
I have array like this:

```
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
]
```

I want to get result like this:
`['1595','8886','1112']`

But when I use this code:

```
array_demo.map(function(i) {
    return i.slice(1).join();
});
```

Result: `['1595,8886', '1112']`

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could destructure the array and take the rest without the first element and flatten this array using [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
var array = [['1st', '1595', '8886'], ['2nd', '1112']],
    result = array.flatMap(([_, ...a]) => a);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) works as well.

```js
var array = [['1st', '1595', '8886'], ['2nd', '1112']],
    result = array.flatMap(a => a.slice(1));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `join()` use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) on the returned result of `map()`:

```js
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
]
array_demo = array_demo.map(function(i) {
    return i.slice(1);
}).flat();
console.log(array_demo);
```

In one liner using [Arrow function(=>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
]
array_demo = array_demo.map(i => i.slice(1)).flat();
console.log(array_demo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, love your answer and very faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.prototype.flat` followed by a `Array.prototype.filter` to get rid of the non-numeric data in your subarrays:

```js
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
];

const res = array_demo.flat().filter(n=> !isNaN(n));
console.log(res);
```

We could do it using `Array.prototype.reduce` also, if your objective is to remove only the object at the `0th` index:

```js
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
];

const res = array_demo.reduce((r, [_, ...e]) => { r.push(...e); return r}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it working very well, but too much right answer, I don't know where is the best so I choose the faster anwser. Finally, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `array.reduce`, and use it as follows:

```
array_demo.reduce( function(prev, curr, index) {
  return prev.concat(curr.slice(1)); 
} ).slice(1);
```

Thing is, array.map, returns the result for each element in the array. So, in your example, it has two cycles:

1. ['1st', '1595', '8886'] -> returns '1595,8886' because you used join()
2. ['2nd', '1112'] -> returns '1112' also because you used join()

And you get that in an array -> ['1595,8886', '1112'].

Comment: Thanks you very much, very clearly and show me the error, but too much right answer, so I should give green tick for the faster answer.

Comment: Yeah, you should accept the answer that works best for you

Answer (score 1):

array_demo.reduce((acc, array_element) => acc.concat(array_element.slice(1)), [])

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but very very sorry because I can't get you the green tick, have too much right answer. Finally, thanks so much because take your time to help me. :)

Comment: No worries, just pick the one that's cleanest ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
]

var reduced_array = array_demo.reduce((reducedArray, elem) => {
  elem.shift() // Remove the first item
  return reducedArray.concat(elem)
}, [])

console.log(reduced_array)
```

Comment: Thanks very much with your help <3

Answer (score 1):

when we need a single accumulated values, we can use reduce funcions.

```js
var array_demo = [
    ['1st', '1595', '8886'],
    ['2nd', '1112']
]

var l = array_demo.reduce((val, item)=> {
    return val.concat(item.slice(1));
},[]);

console.log(l);
```

Comment: Thanks very much with your help <3